# Two box shadows or it should be two rectangles behind? CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

How should I approach this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozWcw.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! SO isn't a code writing service, and you need to provide code for us to be able to answer your question. I presume they are using a box shadow for this, though. Read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this by overlapping the divs.

See my example below

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="h-32 w-32 bg-blue-700 relative rounded-2xl m-20">
  <div class="h-32 mx-2 w-28 bg-blue-400 mt-3 absolute -z-10 rounded-xl"></div>
  <div class="h-32 mx-4 w-24 bg-blue-200 mt-6 absolute -z-20 rounded-xl"></div>
  <p class="p-4 text-white">Hello  World!
</div>
```